# How to hide all issue and syntax checks in Swift Playground in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, configuration, syntax-error

I'm new to programming and to *Swift*, so I'm not fast at typing code and literally every expression takes time and consideration. I can type
a piece of code and take one or two minutes break to think about my expression. Then, in a moment, *Playground* [alerts me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfsWZ.jpg) that I have forgot about a bracket or used a wrong attribute. It really annoys me and can't concentrate on my code. There've gotta be a function to disable all these auto checks and only run code when I need. Is that possible?

I switched the triangle above the console (in the bottom) to "Manually run". Didn't help.

Right now I have the only workaround of working in a separate text-editor. And I can't say that constant copy-pasting is convenient.